# Can't verify data on Java

Tags: java, validation

I have a problem in Java. I'm trying to check if the input provided only contains decimal number (Number and a ".") This code, provided by my professor, its not really evaluating. And I really can't figure out what is wrong.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MoneyCount {

    public static void check(String s) {
        boolean decimalPoint = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == '.') {
                if (!decimalPoint) {
                    decimalPoint = true;
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "You must enter an integer value");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //retrieve amount due
        String moneyd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount due");
        check(moneyd);
        double amountd = Double.parseDouble(moneyd) * 100;

        String moneyr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter amount you would like to pay");
        check(moneyr);
        double amountr = Double.parseDouble(moneyr) * 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you use `Double.parse(String)` is would that be cheating?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Some people just want to watch the world burn.

Comment: Could you please expand on "it just don't do anything [sic]"?

Comment: What input did you provide?

Comment: The boolean is set to false, it is then checked to see if it is false (which it is) and then exits. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: The idea its to return the user that the value is not Valid, so he want us to use that function

Comment: Instead of all these, you could just use `try-catch` with `Double.parse()` ?

Comment: If I use this function with for example

String s = "HI";
check(S);

It should pop out that its an incorrect input. Right?

Comment: so test with "127.0.0.1"

Comment: Reading the code makes it less clear which `if` the `else` is supposed to match up with. Have you tried adding braces to make that more clear? (even if it doesn't solve your issue)

Comment: What we want its to be able to enter a decimal value like "1.27" ONLY

Comment: @jprofitt I think some teachers like to torture their students

Comment: so what you want is just a single dot in your string...if it is more then you have to display the Message?

Comment: So, after testing your code, what's the question?

Comment: Apart from not printing anything when the value is correct, it seems to work fine for me...

Comment: I did notice that the curly braces aren't paired correctly. Make sure that you have a closing brace for every open brace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this one

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    String moneyd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount due");
    if (check(moneyd)) {
        double amountd = Double.parseDouble(moneyd) * 100;
        System.out.println("ok");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not a valid number");
        System.exit(0);
    }       

}

public static boolean check(String s) {
    boolean decimalPoint = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i = i + 1) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == '.') {
            if (!decimalPoint) {
                decimalPoint = true;
            } else {
                return (false);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Myth, it does not work. It check for the value, accepted it and at the end, does not matter what value you entered it tells its not a vialid number.

Comment: @user3241911 I have checked it once more its is working fine.. 
it gives an output as 'ok' for the valid number and if it is an invalid number(contains more than one '.') it will print not a valid number

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem to figure out what's wrong with your professor's code or to write your own method?

If it's the former, I'd also point out the intent of the error message should be "You must enter a decimal value".

Comment: I just posted my complete code, including professors code.

My intention its to follow his code and figure out whats wrong.

Comment: @user3241911 What's the intention of the `check` method?

Answer (score 0):

try changing your code like this

```
public static void check(String s) {
    boolean decimalPoint = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length();i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == '.') {
            if (!decimalPoint) {
                decimalPoint = true;
            }else{
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Not a valid number (contains more than one .)");
               System.exit(0);

            }
        }
    }
    if (decimalPoint) {
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "You must enter an integer value");// you need only integer as input
          System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

you must show the message only after checking the whole string.
That is after completing the loop

Comment: While it's nice you solved the OP's problem with a nice code dump it might be nice to explain why they should use it...and I don't think it will pass `10.10.10`...

Comment: either use `i++` or just change it to `for (char ch : s.toCharArray())`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I was just try to make the code work. Sorry if I made a mess

Comment: This is the way I try to evaluate

`String moneyd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount due"); 
        check(moneyd);
        double amountd = Double.parseDouble(moneyd) * 100;`

Comment: @user3241911 I have added a new answer please go through it

Answer (score 0):

Start with a desk check (oh dear lord, I never thought I'd say that again)...

Basically all this method does is check to see if the `s` contains more than one `.` character

Starting with `s` equal to `123.123`

- `decimalPoint` = `false`
- When `i` = `0`, `s.charAt(i)` will be `1`.
- When `i` = `1`, `s.charAt(i)` will be `2`.
- When `i` = `2`, `s.charAt(i)` will be `3`.
- When `i` = `3`, `s.charAt(i)` will be `.`.
- `decimalPoint` is `false`, change `decimalPoint` to `true`
- When `i` = `4`, `s.charAt(i)` will be `1`.
- When `i` = `5`, `s.charAt(i)` will be `2`.
- When `i` = `6`, `s.charAt(i)` will be `3`.

Starting with `s` equal to `1.2.3`

- `decimalPoint` = `false`
- When `i` = `0`, `s.charAt(i)` will be `1`.
- When `i` = `1`, `s.charAt(i)` will be `.`.
- `decimalPoint` is `false`, change `decimalPoint` to `true`
- When `i` = `2`, `s.charAt(i)` will be `2`.
- When `i` = `3`, `s.charAt(i)` will be `.`.
- `decimalPoint` is `true`, show error message and exit

Starting with `s` equal to `123`

- `decimalPoint` = `false`
- When `i` = `0`, `s.charAt(i)` will be `1`.
- When `i` = `1`, `s.charAt(i)` will be `2`.
- When `i` = `2`, `s.charAt(i)` will be `3`.
- `decimalPoint` is `false`

So the only case which breaks is the second one...Note, this method does not take into consideration what might occur if you enter alpha characters...but that's not what it's designed for...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the try and catch to verify if the string is a decimal or not like the above code:

```
public static void check(String s) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "You must enter an integer value");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually worked! But I want to understand why he's does not work.

I will copy now my whole code

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by **"its not really evaluating"**.

The way I understand the code :

- It works fine if you enter a correct number (ex: "1", "24.2")
- Shows an error dialog if you enter an incorrect number (ex: "1.5.6")
- Throws an exception on anything else (ex: "blabla", "1,2")